# multiple label on same line with equal stretchable width

Tags: ios

I want 2 UI labels on the same row with equal stretchable width on any screen size and any orientation,

I tried content hugging and content compression also but I couldn't get the exact output like below.

[image]

Comment: use stack view and use it "fill equally" in distribution properties.

Comment: stack view does not support sizeto fit property for the dynamic label text

Comment: There are many ways to do it. A simple way is to connect them from edge to edge like so: |<->Label1<->Label2<->| Then make the labels equal width.

Comment: you can use stack view to achieve this or you have to add variants for size class to achieve it without stackview

Comment: @vijaybalans Did you set equalWidth constraint on both?

Answer (score 1):

StackView is working properly. check below

1. Take two labels within stackView

[image]

2. Set StackView property

[image]

3. output

[image]

> Edit

Multiple line output

[image]

Comment: @vijaybalans It is also working properly, I checked this also. Probably you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Set the leading, trailing ,top and height constraints of both the labels and then select both the labels in the storyboard and set the equal widths for both the labels.

Example video is given here.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AuXPqLJxbbvxO-f-Hn70thBsFR-sgC7r